# How to get all the collaboration details for user for all the folders in box.com?

Tags: box-api

I have a requirement according to which, I have to fetch the collaboration details of a user(who is admin at box) on all the folders existing in the box account.

To be more clear, if I have 3 folders in box account and user is collaborated on 2 folders as an admin then I want the collaboration details of the user on those 2 folders??

I checked there are API calls for retriving collaboration details with specific collaboration ID and on specific folder but I'm not able to get how to do so on multiple forlders...

Any suggestions or help on this??

Answer (score 1):

Collaborations are fetched on a per folder basis, not for multiple folders at one time. This can be done through a GET request on /folders/{id}/collaborations documented here: http://developers.box.com/docs/#collaborations-retrieve-a-collaboration

Comment: hmm not very batch friendly